# File I/O assignment

Tags: c++

I am working on an assignment, and the instruction is below:

> This fifth assignment will allow you to better explore the concept of File I/O within the C++ programming language.
>
> For this assignment, you are going to read-in (using C++ File I/O) the contents of a text file (.txt) and calculate the letter grade for a given student based upon weighted averages and write this out to a text file (.txt). We will use the weights as outlined in the Syllabus for this course: Assignments: 50%, Participation: 10%, Midterm Exam: 20%, Final Exam: 20%. Your program should read-in the grade category and then each of the respective scores separated/delimited by a comma.
>
> Once you have finished reading the contents of the file you will need to invoke a function, calculateLetterGrade, that has a return type of void and two parameters: one of type double with By-Value semantics and the other of type char with By-Reference semantics. Your program should then write this calculated grade to another user specified text file (.txt) before terminating. You are expected to check to ensure that each respective file opens and that you properly close your file(s). The output file should have a score of 85.8 and letter grade B

Here is my code:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
void calculateLetterGrade(double score, char &grade);

int main(){

   std::string fileName("");
   char grade;
   double totalScore(0);

   std::cout << "Welcome to the great Grade Calculator!" << std::endl;
   
   std::cout << "Please enter the file you wish to open: ";
   std::cin >> fileName;

   // open file to read
   std::ifstream file(fileName);
   
   //display the file on the console
   if(file.is_open())
   {
       std::cout << "Reading from file " << fileName << "...\n";
       std::cout << "Here is your file " << std::endl;
       
       while(std::getline(file, fileName))
       {
            std::cout << fileName << std::endl; 
       }
   }
   else
   {
        std::cout << "Unable to open file. " << std::endl;  
   }
        

   // loop upto end of file
   while(!file.eof())
   {
       // read type
       std::string gradeCategory("");
       file >> gradeCategory; //stream extraction

       // assign the weight in each category
       double weight(0);

       if(gradeCategory == "Assignments")
       {
           weight = 0.5; //50%
       }
       else if(gradeCategory == "Participation")
       {
           weight = 0.1; //10%
       }
       else if(gradeCategory == "Midterm" || gradeCategory == "Final")
       {
           weight = 0.2; //20%
       }

       double total(0), count(0);
       
       // read count of scores for type
       file >> count;

       // loop for count times
       for(int i = 0; i < count; i++)
       {
           // read score and add to total
           double score;
           file >> score;
           total = total+score;
       }
       
       // calculate average and add weighted score to totalScore
       double average = total/count;
       totalScore = totalScore+(average*weight);
       
   } 
   
   // close file
   file.close();

   // call function to get grade
   std::cout << "Calculating grades...\n";
   calculateLetterGrade(totalScore,grade);

   // read output filename and open it
   std::cout << "Save To (Filename): ";
   std::cin >> fileName;

   std::ofstream fileForGrade(fileName);

   // write score to file 
   fileForGrade << totalScore;

   // write grade to file and then close file
   fileForGrade << grade;

   fileForGrade.close();

   std::cout << "Score & Letter Grade written to file: " << fileName << std::endl;

   std::cout << "Thank you for using my program, have a bless day!" << std::endl;

   return 0;
}

// function to calculate grade by give score
void calculateLetterGrade(double score, char &grade){
   // assign 'A' if score greater than or equal to 90
   if(score>=90){
       grade = 'A';
   }
   // assign 'B' if score greater than or equal to 80
   else if(score>=80){
       grade = 'B';
   }
   // assign 'C' if score greater than or equal to 70
   else if(score>=70){
       grade = 'C';
   }
   // assign 'D' if score greater than or equal to 60
   else if(score>=60){
       grade = 'D';
   }
   // assign 'F', means fail
   else{
       grade = 'F';
   }
}
```

My code compiles, but the output file comes out to be `0 F`. Can someone point out what I did wrong in the code?

---

**UPDATE**: here is my latest code:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
void calculateLetterGrade(double score, char &grade);

int main(){

   std::string fileName("");
   char grade;
   double totalScore(0);

   std::cout << "Welcome to the great Grade Calculator!" << std::endl;
   
   std::cout << "Please enter the file you wish to open: ";
   std::cin >> fileName;

   // open file to read
   std::ifstream file(fileName);
   
   //display the file on the console
   if(file.is_open())
   {
       std::cout << "Reading from file " << fileName << "...\n";
       std::cout << "Here is your file " << std::endl;
       
       std::string line;
       while(std::getline(file, line))
       {
            std::cout << line << std::endl;
            
            std::istringstream iss(line);
            
            std::string gradeCategory;
            iss >> gradeCategory;
             
            // assign the weight in each category
            double weight(0);

            if(gradeCategory == "Assignments")
           {
                weight = 0.5; //50%
           }
            else if(gradeCategory == "Participation")
           {
                weight = 0.1; //10%
           }
            else if(gradeCategory == "Midterm" || gradeCategory == "Final")
           {
                weight = 0.2; //20%
           }
           
           double total(0); 
           int count(0);
       
           // read count of scores for type
           iss >> count;

           // loop for count times
           for(int i = 0; i < count; ++i)
           {
               // read score and add to total
               double score;
               iss >> score;
               total += score;
           }
           // calculate average and add weighted score to totalScore
           double average = total/count;
           totalScore = totalScore+(average*weight);    
       }
      
   }
   else
   {
        std::cout << "Unable to open file. " << std::endl;  
   }
        

   // close file
   file.close();

   // call function to get grade
   std::cout << "Calculating grades...\n";
   calculateLetterGrade(totalScore,grade);

   // read output filename and open it
   std::cout << "Save To (Filename): ";
   std::cin >> fileName;

   std::ofstream fileForGrade(fileName);

   // write score to file 
   fileForGrade << totalScore;

   // write grade to file and then close file
   fileForGrade << " " << grade;

   fileForGrade.close();

   std::cout << "Score & Letter Grade written to file: " << fileName << std::endl;

   std::cout << "Thank you for using my program, have a bless day!" << std::endl;

   return 0;
}

// function to calculate grade by give score
void calculateLetterGrade(double score, char &grade){
   // assign 'A' if score greater than or equal to 90
   if(score>=90){
       grade = 'A';
   }
   // assign 'B' if score greater than or equal to 80
   else if(score>=80){
       grade = 'B';
   }
   // assign 'C' if score greater than or equal to 70
   else if(score>=70){
       grade = 'C';
   }
   // assign 'D' if score greater than or equal to 60
   else if(score>=60){
       grade = 'D';
   }
   // assign 'F', means fail
   else{
       grade = 'F';
   }
}
```

And here is my input file named `grade.txt`:

```
Assignments
75,86,90,80,95,100
Participation
90
Midterm
75
Final
90
```

Comment: FYI, when making edits to your questions, please do so in way that doesn't invalidate existing comments/answers that refer to the original question.

Comment: A debugger (tool) would be beneficial for helping find issues in your code.  The sooner you learn to use one, the better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After the 1st `while` loop reads all of the file, `file`'s position is at the *end* of the file. You need to call [`file.seekg(0)`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/seekg) to reset the position back to the *beginning* of the file before you can read the contents again in the 2nd `while` loop.

```cpp
std::ifstream file(fileName);
   
...

while(std::getline(file, fileName))
{
    std::cout << fileName << std::endl; 
}
        
file.seekg(0); // <-- ADD THIS!

...
```

That being said, consider combining the 2 loops.  You can use `std::istringstream` to parse each line that is read.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>

...

std::ifstream file(fileName);
   
if (file.is_open())
{
    ...
       
    std::string line;
    while (std::getline(file, line))
    {
        std::cout << line << std::endl; 

        std::istringstream iss(line);

        std::string gradeCategory;
        iss >> gradeCategory;
        ...

        int count = 0;
        iss >> count;

        double total = 0.0;
        for (int i = 0; i < count; ++i)
        {
            double score;
            iss >> score;
            total += score;
        }
       
        ...
    }
}
else
{
    std::cout << "Unable to open file. " << std::endl;  
}
        
...
```

---

**UPDATE**: given that we can now see what you input file actually looks like, the code shown so far will not be able to read it correctly.  You will have to make some additional logic changes to the reading loop, eg:

```cpp
...

std::string line;
while (std::getline(file, line))
{
    std::cout << line << std::endl;
            
    // assign the weight in each category
    std::string gradeCategory = line;
    double weight = 0.0;

    if (gradeCategory == "Assignments")
    {
        weight = 0.5; //50%
    }
    else if (gradeCategory == "Participation")
    {
        weight = 0.1; //10%
    }
    else if (gradeCategory == "Midterm" || gradeCategory == "Final")
    {
        weight = 0.2; //20%
    }
           
    // read scores and add to total
    std::getline(file, line);
    std::istringstream iss(line);
    double score, total = 0.0; 
    int count = 0;
    char comma;

    while (iss >> score)
    {
        total += score;
        ++count;
        iss >> comma;
    }

    if (count != 0)
    {
        // calculate average and add weighted score to totalScore
        double average = total / count;
        totalScore += (average * weight);
    }
}

...
```

[Demo](https://ideone.com/9NS77J)

Comment: thank you very much for your answer. Do you mean that it will be better off if I just take out the entire 2nd while loop?

Comment: Merge the two loops together into one loop, yes.

Comment: I did that but the result is now "-nan F". Do you think the problem might be in my calculation?

Comment: @noobieprogrammer can't answer that without seeing your updated code, and your input file.

Comment: I updated my code on top. I'm still new at this website so I don't know how to include files into the comments but my input file is named grade.txt with everything inside as follows: 
Assignments
75,86,90,80,95,100
Participation
90
Midterm
75
Final
90

Comment: "*I don't know how to include files into the comments*" - don't.  Include the actual contents of the file as plain text in your question instead. In any case, the file you just showed does not match the logic of your code. There is no `count` value present after each `gradeCategory`, and also the `Assignments` category has a **comma-separated** list of numbers, but your code doesn't account for the commas at all. Or the fact that the `gradeCategory` and numbers are actually on **separate lines**. See, this is why it is important to provide these kinds of *relevant* details up front!

Comment: You are going to have to use a different parsing scheme to handle this file.  For instance, by replacing `iss >> count;` with another `std::getline()` call, and then splitting that 2nd line into substrings on commas, and then converting each substring into an `int`.  Otherwise, you will have to correct the file instead to use a different format that better matches the code you already have (which i doubt you can do, if this is a school assignment).

Comment: I have updated my answer

Comment: Thank you very much for your feedbacks. When you say 2nd line, do you mean the 2nd line in the input file?

Comment: Yes. For instance, you will need one call to `std::getline()` to read in `Assignments`, then another call to `std::getline()` to read in `75,86,90,80,95,100`, then another for `Participation`, and another for `90`, and so on...